# IntelliJ Idea cursor-wrap goes to infinity and beyond instead of next line on Windows

Tags: windows, cursor, intellij-idea

If I reach left-most end of a line and press left-arrow it doesn't take me to the previous line.

Similarly, if I keep pressing right arrow, the cursor keeps going towards infinity, without ever moving to 
the next line.

How do I change this behavior to desired one?

Answer (score 8):

Find Tools -> IDE Options -> Editor (in OSX it's Preferences -> Editor). In the area entitled "Virtual Space" uncheck "Allow placement of caret after end of line". Click "Apply" and you're good to go.

Comment: See also my reply to the same question at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior/4493742#4493742.

Comment: That's not the preference location, possibly due to a menu change. To find it I used Help > Find Action > "Virtual Space"